# phpseclib - exec works once, then closes connection

Tags: ssh, phpseclib

I am running ssh->exec on a router, with a packethandler.
The first call works fine -- I see results.
The second call never gets any results.  In the php log I see the message:
Connection closed prematurely in C:\temp\php\Net\SSH2.php on line 3939
Is there something I need to do to keep the connection open long enough for the second call?

Code fragment:

```
function packet_handler($str) {
    echo "results from remote unit: $str \n";
}

$sCmd="who";
$ssh->setTimeout(3);

$ssh->exec("$sCmd", 'packet_handler');  // I see results for this call
//usleep(3000000);  

$ssh->exec("$sCmd", 'packet_handler');  // I never see results for this call
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's something some routers just kinda do. My recommendation: try `$ssh->exec("$sCmd && $sCmd")` or `$ssh->exec("$sCmd; $sCmd")`. You should be able to put a sleep in between the two `$sCmd`'s as well

Comment: I tried experimenting with sleep, but couldn't get it to work.  I had an idea to login, run the command, disconnect, then login again.  But I don't know how to disconnect.

Comment: I'll try the multiple commands.  But I do want to run the command periodically -- collect the info now, but then circle back and collect it again in another minute or so.

Comment: Try doing `$ssh->disconnect()` and then `$ssh->ping()`. You could also do `unset($ssh)`, which'll call phpseclib's destructor, which'll call `$ssh->disconnect()`, but then you wouldn't be able to use `$ssh->ping()` to reconnect.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by performing an unset as you described, then creating a new connection.  I also ran on a Juniper router, and did not encounter the disconnect issue.  So maybe this problem is unique to Cisco IOS.